# MongoS connection times out from application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, connection-timeout

Our nodejs applications connect to mongos instances and these instances connect to mongod instances.

Randomly we get timeouts from our application with the following error

```
connection 10 to <IP of mongos>:27017 timed out
```

Our applications have a pool size of 20.

These timeouts are mostly spikes and exist for 1-2 seconds and then normality is ensured.

The timeouts occur only on a single instance and aren't spread out. But they occur on different instances at different times.

How do I debug this issue further ?

The logs on mongos instances don't have any message related to disconnection

Answer (score 0):

Some of your query is taking a long time. You can avoid timeout by passing options with connectTimeoutMS,reconnectTries

```
    var uri = 'mongodb://USENAME:PASSWORD@host1:port1,host2:port2/database?authSource=admin';

    var options = {};
    options.server = {
      auto_reconnect: true,
      poolSize: 5,
      socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 },
      reconnectTries: 3000
    };

    options.replset = {  //For Replica set
      auto_reconnect: true,
      poolSize: 5,
      socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 },
      reconnectTries: 3000
    };

    var db = mongoose.createConnection(uri, options);
   mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('MONGODB ERROR MONGOOSE LEVEL ' + server, err);
    });

    db.on('connecting', function() {
      console.info('MONGODB ' + server + ' connecting.');
    });

    db.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('MONGODB ERROR ' + server, err);
    });

    db.on('close', function(err) {
      console.log('MONGODB CLOSE ' + server, err);
    });

    db.on('connected', function() {
      console.log('MONGODB ' + server + ' connected successfully.');
    });

    db.once('open', function callback() {
      console.log('MONGODB ' + server + ' opened successfully.');
    });

    db.on('reconnected', function() {
      console.log('MONGODB ' + server + ' reconnected.');
    });

    db.on('timeout', function() {
      console.log('MONGODB ' + server + ' timeout.');
    });

    db.on('disconnected', function() {
      console.log('MONGODB ' + server + ' disconnected');
    });
```

Comment: query timeouts would not result in connection timeouts right ?

Comment: also my connectTimeoutMS is set to 120 seconds so that is a large enough timeout right ?

Comment: did you pass timeout parameter in query?